# how to install spec2 with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am very new to sbt, and I'm trying to add dependencies `spec2` with spec2.

I've added the following code in build.sbt as spec2 official site said:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.6.4" % "test"

scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")
```

But It didn't involve the spec2 as dependencies for my project after running 'sbt compile'

Comment: how did you check if it's involved or not in your project?

Comment: The IDEA tell me that.

Answer (score 0):

`sbt compile` will only compile sources, it does not look at tests. Run `sbt test` instead.

Comment: thanks, I have solve that. As the idea didn't apply the changes of the build.sbt. I have to import the project again. I think I need a way to apply the idea apply the changes of the build.sbt as soon as the changes finished.

Comment: In IntelliJ preferences: `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `SBT` > `Use auto-import` to apply the build file changes automatically.